# Find all positive number $n$ such that $n-1 \mid 1 + 10^n + 10^{2n}$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

> Find all number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
> $$n-1 \mid 1 + 10^n + 10^{2n}$$

If $n-1$is prime, it's clear that $n-1\mid 10^{n-2} - 1$ if $n\ne 3, 6$. So, $$0\equiv 1 + 10^n + 10^{2n} \equiv 1 + 10^2 + 10^4\mod n-1\implies n=4, 8, 14, 38$$

But I can't continue after this. I also found that $n = 2, 4, 8, 14, 22, 38, 40, 92, 112, 260, 1652$ works. Is this an open question?

Comment: (1) Is the $10^2$ in the problem statement not a typo? (2) How do $n-1$ is a prime and $n \neq 3, 6$ imply $n-1 \mid 10^{n-2}-2$?

Comment: $n=40,112,1652$ do not seem to be correct. For example, if you plug in Mod[1+10^2+10^(2*40),40-1] into WolframAlpha, the result is 6.

Using Mathematica, for the first 100 000 positive integers the solution is $n \in \{2, 4, 8, 14, 38, 92, 260, 482, 502, 1262, 3368, 6020\}$

Comment: Re: my previous comment, when $10^2$ is replaced by $10^n$ as suggested above, your solutions are correct, though there are more solutions between 260 and 1652.

Comment: @VTand yes, they're typo. I've fixed it just now, thank you!

Comment: @RandyMarsh I found them by coding. Maybe there is some mistake in my code. Thank you for noticing it!

Comment: What is the source of the question?

Comment: @BartMichels I found this question from Mathematical olympiad preparation book. I guess this is problem has a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Comment: We rewrite A as:

$A=10^{2n}+10^n+1=(10^n+1)^2-10^n$

Suppose n is even $n=2k$, the we may write:

$A=(10^{2k}+1-10^k)(10^{2k}+1+10^k)$

For $k=1$ we have:

$A=91\times 3\times 37$

For $k=2$ we have:

$A=9901\times 3\times 13\times 37$

We can continue and find infinite factors for $k\in \mathbb N$. Each of these factors can be a candidate for n, i. e we for example can have:

$(n-1)= 91, 9901, 3, 7, 13, 37, . . .$

$n=92, 9902, 4, 8, 14, 38, . . .$

Generally we may write:

$10^{2n}+10^n+1\equiv 10^{2k}+10^k+1=(91, 9901 . . .)\times (3\times 7\times 13\times 37 . . .)$

For example if you take $n=38$ you will get new factors in addition to factors previously found including $n-1=37$ which meets the condition. That is solutions  make a recursive relation. Hence the relation can have infinite solutions.